# How to run an aiohttp server in a thread?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

This example of aiohttp server in a thread fails with an `RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.` error:

```
import threading
from aiohttp import web


def aiohttp_server():
    def say_hello(request):
        return web.Response(text='Hello, world')

    app = web.Application(debug=True)
    app.add_routes([web.get('/', say_hello)])
    web.run_app(app)


t = threading.Thread(target=aiohttp_server)
t.start()
```

How to run a aiohttp server in thread?

Comment: Maybe this example will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650760/python3-and-asyncio-how-to-implement-websocket-server-as-asyncio-instance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create `handler` in main thread and manually create an event loop in child thread.

```
import asyncio
import threading
from aiohttp import web


def aiohttp_server():
    def say_hello(request):
        return web.Response(text='Hello, world')

    app = web.Application(debug=True)
    app.add_routes([web.get('/', say_hello)])
    handler = app.make_handler()
    return handler


def run_server(handler):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    server = loop.create_server(handler, host='127.0.0.1', port=8089)
    loop.run_until_complete(server)
    loop.run_forever()


t = threading.Thread(target=run_server, args=(aiohttp_server(),))
t.start()
```

## Update

For new `aiohttp`, use the following, thank @Auyer for notification.

```
import asyncio
import threading
from aiohttp import web


def aiohttp_server():
    def say_hello(request):
        return web.Response(text='Hello, world')

    app = web.Application()
    app.add_routes([web.get('/', say_hello)])
    runner = web.AppRunner(app)
    return runner


def run_server(runner):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(runner.setup())
    site = web.TCPSite(runner, 'localhost', 8080)
    loop.run_until_complete(site.start())
    loop.run_forever()


t = threading.Thread(target=run_server, args=(aiohttp_server(),))
t.start()
```

Comment: This example code don't include thread usage example. How can i test it with thread ?

Comment: You mean like that https://0bin.net/paste/Uc6NLG+i+0uugiOQ#ceJJ6bUmB73woV7ogx5vsCyU4JkNenQHeqP-e811j9d ? It produce `RuntimeError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread` error.

Comment: Well, you are right. We have to create handler in main thread and then use child thread to execute `loop`. I will update my answer.

Comment: Whether you'd do this in the case of threading or not, I dont know, however you can use an `async def` before the `say_hello` to have it async. The `make_handler` is very useful! This helped solve another issue.

Comment: `DeprecationWarning: Application.make_handler(...) is deprecated, use AppRunner API instead.`

I'm looking for a solution for this warning, and will post her if I find it.

Comment: Why is it necessary to create the web runner in the main thread? I tested and it works fine when created in the new thread. (I suppose it's to [handle  the requests in the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55133510/aiohttp-slowness-with-threading). Why is that useful?)

Answer (score 2):

We must use `app.make_handler` handler in main thread, example:

```
import asyncio
import threading
from aiohttp import web

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()


def say_hello(request):
    return web.Response(text='Hello, world')


app = web.Application(debug=True)
app.add_routes([web.get('/', say_hello)])

handler = app.make_handler()
server = loop.create_server(handler, host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)


def aiohttp_server():
    loop.run_until_complete(server)
    loop.run_forever()


t = threading.Thread(target=aiohttp_server)
t.start()
```

Comment: Is this a part of question? You shouldn't add an answer instead of editing question.

Comment: You are "abusing" the event loop of the main thread, which may work in a simple test code, but it is not a good idea in general. Either create one yourself (as in @Sraw's answer) or just call ```get_event_loop()``` from inside the thread (according to [its source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/asyncio/events.py#L632) it will create a new event loop for the thread in this case)

Comment: @tevemadar `get_event_loop()` will only create a new event loop in main thread, see this condition: `isinstance(threading.current_thread(), threading._MainThread)`

Comment: @Sraw oops, I thought it was an inner ```if```

Comment: @Sraw no, it is a response of question.

Answer (score 2):

There's a new API intended for this use case:

https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_advanced.html#application-runners

```
from aiohttp import web
import asyncio


async def healthz(request):
    return web.Response(text="OK")

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.get("/", healthz)])


async def runner():
    runner = web.AppRunner(app)
    await runner.setup()
    site = web.TCPSite(runner, "localhost", 8080)
    await site.start()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(runner())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use `web.run_app`, just create a new event loop (and set `handle_signals=False` to avoid `RuntimeError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread`):

```py
import threading
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web

def aiohttp_server():
    def say_hello(request):
        return web.Response(text='Hello, world')

    asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())  # create a new event loop here
    app = web.Application(debug=True)
    app.add_routes([web.get('/', say_hello)])
    web.run_app(app, handle_signals=False)
```