# aiohttp slowness with threading

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading, aiohttp

I copied the code from [How to run an aiohttp server in a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610074/how-to-run-an-aiohttp-server-in-a-thread). It runs fine. So I am adding one second sleep. When I launch 10 requests at the same time. The average response time is 9 seconds. Why is that? Wouldn't all requests coming back in a little bit over 1 second?

```
import asyncio
import threading
from aiohttp import web
import time

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()


def say_hello(request):
    time.sleep(1)
    return web.Response(text='Hello, world')


app = web.Application(debug=True)
app.add_routes([web.get('/', say_hello)])

handler = app.make_handler()
server = loop.create_server(handler, host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)


def aiohttp_server():
    loop.run_until_complete(server)
    loop.run_forever()


t = threading.Thread(target=aiohttp_server)
t.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use asyncio.sleep instead.  Your setup is running coros that hard sleep 1 second before they yield to the event loop. So if you gather a bunch of them you have to wait that 1 second for each one serially.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting the server in a second thread, but all of the requests are served from the same thread. The call to `time.sleep` blocks this thread and does not yield to the event loop so that the requests are effectively processed serially.

If you genuinely want to use sleep for a delay in the response you could use `asyncio.sleep` instead, which yields to the event loop.

However I expect you are using it as a placeholder for another blocking function. In this case you need to run this in another thread to the main server. The example below shows how to do this using `run_in_executor` and `asyncio.wait`.

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time


def blocking_func(seconds: int) -> int:
    time.sleep(seconds)
    return seconds


async def view_page(request: web.Request):
    seconds = int(request.query.get("seconds", 5))
    executor = request.app["executor"]
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = loop.run_in_executor(executor, blocking_func, seconds)
    completed, pending = await asyncio.wait([task])
    result = task.result()
    return web.Response(text=f"Waited {result} second(s).")


def create_app():
    app = web.Application()
    app.add_routes([web.get("/", view_page)])
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
    app["executor"] = executor
    return app


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    web.run_app(app)
```