# server in a thread (Python3.9.0+aiohttp) : RuntimeError: can't register atexit after shutdown

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, aiohttp

This snippet of code (a minimal server running in a thread, code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610074/how-to-run-an-aiohttp-server-in-a-thread)) works fine with Python3.8.3 but raises an error message with Python3.9.0:

```
import asyncio
import threading
from aiohttp import web


def aiohttp_server():
    def say_hello(request):
        return web.Response(text='Hello, world')

    app = web.Application()
    app.add_routes([web.get('/', say_hello)])
    runner = web.AppRunner(app)
    return runner


def run_server(runner):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(runner.setup())
    site = web.TCPSite(runner, 'localhost', 8080)
    loop.run_until_complete(site.start())
    loop.run_forever()


t = threading.Thread(target=run_server, args=(aiohttp_server(),))
t.start()
```

The error message:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/alkhinoos/nikw/nikw/z2.py", line 21, in run_server
    loop.run_until_complete(site.start())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/web_runner.py", line 121, in start
    self._server = await loop.create_server(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1460, in create_server
    infos = await tasks.gather(*fs, loop=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1400, in _create_server_getaddrinfo
    infos = await self._ensure_resolved((host, port), family=family,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1396, in _ensure_resolved
    return await loop.getaddrinfo(host, port, family=family, type=type,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 856, in getaddrinfo
    return await self.run_in_executor(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 809, in run_in_executor
    executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 49, in __getattr__
    from .thread import ThreadPoolExecutor as te
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 37, in <module>
    threading._register_atexit(_python_exit)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 1374, in _register_atexit
    raise RuntimeError("can't register atexit after shutdown")
RuntimeError: can't register atexit after shutdown
```

What's going on ? The same problem appears with Python 3.9.1. Is this problem solved with Python 3.9.2 ? Maybe [a relative issue here](https://bugs.python.org/issue42647).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned in Python manual - [Thread Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects)

> Other threads can call a thread’s join() method. This blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join() method is called is terminated.

After calling `t.start()` in main thread, the main thread will exit. Then the process is ended.

If you want to run the child thread forever or until it exits, you should call `t.join()` in main thread after `t.start()`.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you did, but I used `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` and the error is resolved!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get this sorted by importing the ThreadPoolExecutor module, before calling any of my main application code - so at the top of my `main.py` start-up script.

`thread_pool_ref = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`

Just the act of importing the module early (before any threads are initialised) was enough to fix the error. There is an on-going issue around how this module must be present in the main thread, before any child threads import or use any related threading library code.

The inspiration for this fix came from [this post on the Python bugs site](https://bugs.python.org/issue42647). My issue was specifically around `boto3` library, but the fix is applicable across the board.