# ERROR: can't register atexit after shutdown

Tags: python

Hi im new to Python and am doing some 3d animation and was given the task of creating two thermometers with one's mercury moving twice as fast as the other at the same time, I decided to use threads and I keep getting the error message 'can't register atexit after shutdown' I'm unsure why I keep getting this error help apreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from threading import Thread

pos2=-5
mcr=1.7
r=2
br=r*1.2


#Thermomiter cylinder
tc=cylinder(pos=vector(0,0,0),size=vector(9,r,r),color=color.white,opacity=0.35)
#Thermomiter Mecury
tm=cylinder(pos=vector(0.2,0,0),size=vector(8.5,mcr,mcr,),color=color.red)
#Thermomiter Bottom
tb=sphere(pos=vector(-(r/5),0,0),size=vector(br,br,br),color=color.white,opacity=0.35)
#Mercury Bottom
mb=sphere(pos=vector(-(r/5),0,0),size=vector(br-.2,br-.2,br-.2),color=color.red)
#Markers
for j in range(1,9,1):
        Marker=box(pos=vector(0+j,-(r/2)+0.15,0),size=vector(0.1,.1,r/2-0.15),color=color.white,opacity=0.8)

# Second Thermomiter
tc2=cylinder(pos=vector(0,0,pos2),size=vector(9,r,r),color=color.white,opacity=0.35)
#Thermomiter Mecury
tm2=cylinder(pos=vector(0.2,0,pos2),size=vector(8.5,mcr,mcr,),color=color.red)
#Thermomiter Bottom
tb2=sphere(pos=vector(-(r/5),0,pos2),size=vector(br,br,br),color=color.white,opacity=0.35)

#Mercury Bottom
mb2=sphere(pos=vector(-(r/5),0,pos2),size=vector(br-.2,br-.2,br-.2),color=color.red)
#Markers
for j in range(1,9,1):
        Markers=box(pos=vector(0+j,-(r/2)+0.15,),size=vector(0.1,.1,r/2-0.15),color=color.white,opacity=0.8)
def Thermomiter1R():
    while True:
        for length in np.linspace(1,8.5,1000):
            rate(250)
            tm.size=vector(length,mcr,mcr)
        for Length in np.linspace(8.5,1,1000):
            rate(250)
            tm.size=vector(Length,mcr,mcr)
def Thermomiter2R():
    while True:
        for length in np.linspace(1,8.5,500):
            rate(250)
            tm2.size=vector(length,mcr,mcr)
        for Length in np.linspace(8.5,1,500):
            rate(250)
            tm2.size=vector(Length,mcr,mcr)

Rate1Thread=Thread(target=Thermomiter1R, args=())
Rate2Thread=Thread(target=Thermomiter2R, args=())
Rate2Thread.daemon=True
Rate1Thread.daemon=True
Rate2Thread.start()
Rate1Thread.start()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [server in a thread (Python3.9.0+aiohttp) : RuntimeError: can't register atexit after shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65467329/server-in-a-thread-python3-9-0aiohttp-runtimeerror-cant-register-atexit-a)

Answer (score 1):

> As mentioned in Python manual - [Thread
> Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects)
>
> > Other threads can call a thread’s join() method. This blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join() method is called is
> > terminated.
>
> After calling `t.start()` in main thread, the main thread will exit.
> Then the process is ended.
>
> If you want to run the child thread forever or until it exits, you
> should call `t.join()` in main thread after `t.start()`.

Take a  look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65467329/server-in-a-thread-python3-9-0aiohttp-runtimeerror-cant-register-atexit-a/68187929#68187929), it might help you.

Comment: Yes Thank you I have implemented this and this has fixed my issue thank you very so much, very appreciated =)